# Sumar datos de Array PHP

Tags: php, array, arraylist, php5

Cuento con el siguiente arreglo:
(en este se encuentran ordenados los datos por factura pero podrían estar revueltos).

```
$datos =[{"factura":88,"total":41587.3942},{"factura":88,"total":43.01},{"factura":88,"total":1472},{"factura":88,"total":117.98},{"factura":88,"total":66.01},{"factura":999,"total":41587.3942},{"factura":999,"total":516.12},{"factura":999,"total":128},{"factura":999,"total":235.96},{"factura":999,"total":330.05}];
```

y quisiera sumar los valores donde la factura sea igual (en este caso son 2 números de factura, por lo tanto mi nuevo arreglo quería

Ejemplo:

```
$totalF =[{"factura":88,"total":41587.3942},{"factura":999,"total":42763.33}];
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿Que haz intentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He traducido tu array de objetos a php, ya que pides que se haga en php.

```
    $datos = [
        ["factura"=>88,"total"=>41587.3942],
        ["factura"=>88,"total"=>43.01],
        ["factura"=>88,"total"=>1472],
        ["factura"=>88,"total"=>117.98],
        ["factura"=>88,"total"=>66.01],
        ["factura"=>999,"total"=>41587.3942],
        ["factura"=>999,"total"=>516.12],
        ["factura"=>999,"total"=>128],
        ["factura"=>999,"total"=>235.96],
        ["factura"=>999,"total"=>330.05]
        ];

    $facturas = [];
    $facturas_id = [];
    foreach($datos as $data){
        if(!in_array($data['factura'],$facturas_id)){
            $facturas[$data['factura']] = $data['total'];
            $facturas_id[] = $data['factura'];
        }
        else{
            $facturas[$data['factura']] += $data['total'];
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($facturas);
    echo '</pre>';
```

La idea es sencilla:

- recorremos el array y creamos antes dos arrays más:
- uno ($facturas_id) que se encargará de almacenar los id's de las facturas. Este array sólo nos va a decir si a medida que vamos recorriendo el array de datos, hemos pasado o no por una factura con ese id. Si no existe ese id de factura en el array, lo meterá dentro; sino no hara nada (no lo meterá dentro, quiero decir).
- el otro ($facturas) va a tener tantos índices como id's de factura haya y sus valores serán lo que se va acumulando en el total a medida que recorremos el bucle foreach.
- Lo que haremos será (a medida que se recorre el bucle): vemos si el id de la factura que estamos evaluando existe o no en el primero de los arrays (en $facturas_id). Si no existe, se entiende que es la primera vez que nos encontramos con ese id de factura, por lo que el total hasta ese momento para ese id es cero, así que simplemente se le asigna el total de esa factura en concreto. Si por el contrario sí que existía el id de la factura en el primero de los arrays ($facturas_id), lo que hacemos es sumar (sobre el segundo de nuestros arrays) en ese mismo índice el valor total a lo que tiene acumulado.

Bueno, la explicación es un poco liosa quizás, pero funcionar funciona.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias m  fue muy util amigo :)

Answer (score 0):

Es posible utilizar la función [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php), de php:

```
$totales = array_reduce($datos, function($a, $x) { 
    $a[$x['factura']] += $x['total'];
    return $a;
}, []);
```

A esta función de PHP se le indica una función que trabaja con dos argumentos: el resultado parcial o acumulado y el dato a iterar de los que componen el array. Lo que hace array_reduce es llamar a tu función una vez por cada elemento del array. Tu función devolverá el resultado parcial de combinar ese elemento con el resultado anterior, partiendo de un resultado inicial que, en este caso, es un array vacío.